# Using a different file when in DEBUG and having that logic in a NuGet package

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

Can you use conditional logic in code packaged into a NuGet package to return a different variable if the solution (that the NuGet package is installed on) is run in Debug or Release mode?

I am working on a framework for our QA department and trying to implement a way to store settings (such as what browser to run the tests against etc.). These are stored in a `Config.json` file and, rather than getting the QAs to edit the default file I want to have a `Config.local.json` file that is .gitingore'd.

I have the following code to switch between the files and this works *if* I have the framework as a project in the overall solution but not if it is compiled into a NuGet package and installed on the solution (the current process of getting the framework).

The reason why we are using a `.json` file is that there is a requirement to be modified after compile for our build agent (TeamCity).

```
        public static string FilePath()
    {
        var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var filePath = string.Empty;

        #if DEBUG
        filePath = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(@"{0}\Settings\Config.local.json", baseDirectory));
        #else
        filePath = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(@"{0}\Settings\Config.json", baseDirectory));
        #endif
        return filePath;
    }
```

Comment: What if you just use the Config.local.json if its found and Config.json otherwise? The build agent won't have a config.local.json file will it?

Comment: The users of your package will be extremely annoyed when they discover why their settings didn't work - ie because your package looked at different configuration files while debugging

Comment: Visual Studio already has mechanisms to handle configuration **and** loading different config files for debug, release, testing, staging, production, or whatever environment the *end programmer* wants to use. Don't surprise people by adding a hard-coded, non-standard way. Instead of helping, you'll double the work people have to do

Comment: Thanks for your passionate response @PanagiotisKanavos. The users, being the 15 people that sit relatively close together so the communication is manageable. I believe my question is pretty clear in that I'm asking for a way to a) have a file that can be used when the QA is running the test locally b) have a file that is just used by the build agent (teamcity) & c) have that file configurable after compile. It also sounds like you know how I can achieve this so any practical answers you could provide would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: @mikez thanks for your comment, I'll give this a go.

Comment: @DSayer and we have debug, release builds, with testing, staging, production environments in TeamCity, staging and production deployments in Octopus. Just don't do that. Visual Studio already has publishing profiles and environments that use the same xdt transforms you use in NuGet. TeamCity and Octopus understand them too. *NuGet* itself can pack and apply [xdt files](http://blog.nuget.org/20130920/how-to-use-nugets-xdt-feature-examples-and-facts.html) during deployment.

Comment: It's a LOT easier to specify separate transforms per environment and build, and combine them as needed, eg. `Release.xdt` and `Testing.xdt` to deploy a release to the testing environment. In fact, that's exactly how VS works. web.config  has a Debug/Release transform by default. The default release tranformation just removed the debug attribute. Publishing profiles add their own transform on top of a base transform, typically Release.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks but that doesn't help, we're not deploying the code anywhere we're running the tests against different environments. Plus the configuration are parameters such as browserType, screen resolution, device type etc. We have different builds for different configurations so we can run all our tests against all supported devices and browsers without having to duplicate code. This is working quite well for us so this isn't going to change. What we would _like_ is a way to have a file to use when running tests locally that doesn't affect the file used by the build server.

Comment: @DSayer does my answer below work for you? I can't see any votes for that but it is chosen as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the start up of your program, you could do something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
MyPackage.PathProvider.Debug = true;
#endif
```

Where, MyPackage is the Nuget package you mentioned, PathProvider is a class inside that, and Debug is a static bool in that class.

So, inside your nuget packaged class, you should have something like this:

```
public static bool Debug = false;
public static string FilePath()
{
    var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var filePath = string.Empty;

    if(Debug)
       filePath = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(@"{0}\Settings\Config.local.json", baseDirectory));
    else
       filePath = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(@"{0}\Settings\Config.json", baseDirectory));
    return filePath;
}
```